# In datatables live DOM ordering what is $.fn.datatables?

Tags: javascript, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am following the example

https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html

to allow live sorting on a table that has input fields.

I do not understand

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-text'] = function  ( settings, col )
{
    return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
        return $('input', td).val();
    } );
}
```

Specifically what is this ?

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order
```

$ = jquery, I have that

but fn is undefined

Do I need a plugin to get this working? I am using npm. I need to install something?

---

My packages.json has these dependencies(amongst others)

```
"datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
"datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.19",
"datatables.net-fixedcolumns-bs4": "^3.2.6",
"datatables.net-fixedheader-bs4": "^3.1.5",
"datatables.net-responsive-bs4": "^2.2.3",
"datatables.net-scroller-bs4": "^2.0.0",
"datatables.net-select-bs4": "^1.2.7",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
```

Comment: `jQuery.fn.dataTable` is an alias for the `DataTable` object, defined in the DataTables source code. And `$` is the jQuery alias for itself.  `$.fn.dataTable.ext.order` is a static function and is accessed through the `$.fn.dataTable` object.

Comment: If `fn` is undefined, perhaps one or more scripts have been blocked or there is a naming conflict. But there are no extra plugins that should be needed, based on what you have described.

Comment: Perhaps you have another script overriding `$`? Try using `jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.order`...`$.fn` is actually just a shorthand. If none is present jQuery is not loaded. Remember: You need to have jQuery loaded before you can do anything with DataTables. You do not need any plugins, what you are trying to accomplish is a little ordering plugin itself.

Comment: Ah - yes - @davidkonrad - jQuery should definitely be listed & loaded first. (I need to "see the wood for the trees"). @sawili1495 - are you initializing DataTables inside `$(document).ready(function() {...}`?